# Notification Transports From Observium to Icinga

Tags: nagios, icinga2

I'm trying to redirect some notifications for specific hosts from Observium to Icinga ( Similar to Nagios), can somebody advise which Notification Transports can be used in this case and how can it be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Icinga2 Api](https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/12-icinga2-api/#send-custom-notification) to send custom notifications.